# mySQL SHOW TABLES -> Table names aren't shown

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I want to make a script search for the tables in my database.

I found that you can do that with a query "SHOW TABLES".
After I implemented this and echoed the output on the browser,
it doesn't show the table names as it should do. 
The number of tables is correct, but the output it shows is

```
ArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArray
```

12 times Array for I have 12 tables in my database.

Maybe it is in my code so here it is.

```
function backup_db()
  {
    require_once("../../Connections/chirodon_chirodb.php");

    // Find all tables in the Database
    $count = 0;

    $fetch_Tables = $chirodon_chirodb -> query("SHOW TABLES")  or die(mysql_error());

    while($table = $fetch_Tables -> fetch_array()) {
      $allTables[$count] = $table;
      $count++;
    }

    foreach($allTables as $table) {
      echo $table;
    }

    mysqli_free_result($fetch_Tables);
 }
```

$chirodon_chirodb is my connection to the database.
This can't be the problem, because I've used it several time on my website without any issue.

Comment: Replace `echo $table;` with `var_dump($table);` to see the structure of the array and access the wanted value. Side note : You don't need that `$count` variable here, just use `$allTables[] = ...` without any key and PHP will auto increment the keys by itself.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are fetching an array should it read as follows

```
$allTables[$count] = $table[0];
```

Comment: So you are sure that `$table` in indexed with integers ?